# ¿Como sumo valores de cada columna y después divido esa suma entre la cantidad de valores diferentes de cero en cada columna en dax power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Por ejemplo column1 = 4 column2 = 4 column3 = 0

(column1 + column2 + column3) / 2    (Pongo dos porque la columna 3 no cuenta ya que es igual a cero)

Espero me puedan ayudar gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para sumar los datos de columnas en Power BI deberás de utilizar la formula dax `SUM()`

En este caso sumarias primero la información (SUM(col1) + SUM(col2) + SUM(col)) Y luego tendrías que validar si las sumas de cada uno de ellos supera los 0 datos.

Este sería un ejemplo de como podrías realizarlo a como te entendí.

```
VAR COL1 = IF(SUM(TEST[COL1])>0,1,0)
VAR COL2 = IF(SUM(TEST[COL2])>0,1,0)
VAR COL3 = IF(SUM(TEST[COL3])>0,1,0)
VAR SUMCOL = COL1+COL2+COL3
VAR SUMtotal = (SUM(TEST[COL1]) + SUM(TEST[COL2]) + SUM(TEST[COL3]))
return SUMtotal / SUMCOL
```

Esto claro se debería de ingresar dentro de una medida.

Espero te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Graciasss me sirvio